# MediaPlayer sounds names in for loop

Tags: android

I have 10 sounds on my project named sound1,sound2.... and I wana create them in a for loop acording to the index of the loop. Any ideas how to do it?, this is what I tried:

```
for(int i = 0; i < this.whiteTiles.length ; i++)
        {
            this.whiteTiles[i] = new PianoTile(context, 0, R.raw.sound + "i");
            this.blackTiles[i] = new PianoTile(context, 1, );
        }   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop is correct but you can't use `R.raw.sound + "i"` because:

`R.raw.sound` will return an int (Ex: 0x7f040000), concatenate "i" and return a String. You'll end up referencing a resource that doesn't exist in the generated `R.java` Class.

You should do it as follows:

```
Resources res = getResources();

for(int i = 0; i < this.whiteTiles.length ; i++)
{
    int soundId = res.getIdentifier("sound" + i, "raw", getContext().getPackageName());
    this.whiteTiles[i] = new PianoTile(context, 0, soundId);
    this.blackTiles[i] = new PianoTile(context, 1, );
}
```

Comment: thanks, looks good, but im getting an erroe:"res cannot be resolved".

Comment: Pass a reference of a Context to getResources:  Ex: getApplicationContext().getResources();